# Creating point geometry from varchar (x,y)

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a large table of locations. The locations are in varchar written as (x,y). I need to create a individual point for all of the locations. I have created a point geometry column in the table but can't figure how to create points for the locations from the format that they are in.

geodata  coordinates are in a single column of (x,y)
e.g (52.3852758,4.8682022)

I am using this script but getting error.

update "tlblocation" set geom=ST_GeomFromText(geodata);

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please edit your quetsion, add create table script, sample datas and exepcted result

Comment: Just check the order of your coordinates. Is that point in Amsterdam, by any chance? If so you have them in y,x order, when st_point expect x,y. (Otherwise your point is somewhere off the coast of Somalia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ST_* functions. ie:

```
drop table if exists geosample;
CREATE TABLE geosample(gid serial PRIMARY KEY,  geog geography(POINT) null, pointAsVarchar varchar(100));

insert into geoSample (pointAsVarchar) values
('(-74.06414465351811,40.70677298472955)'),
('(-122.33383026916862,47.62266259856472)'),
('(2.3501235468097144,48.86267330918897)');


update geoSample set geog = st_pointfromtext('POINT'||replace(pointAsVarchar,',',' ')) where 1=1;

select *, st_astext(geog) from geosample;
```

Comment: My coordinates are written as (52.3852758,4.8682022) in the table (including brackets). how do I remove these as well?

Comment: @BenWatson, that would be simpler. Check edited version includes the parentheses.